# Scala initialise sc.parallelise inside "if block" and execute outside loop

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I've a following code :-

```
case class event(id: String, date: String)

object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  var collection = null
  if(some_condition){
     val a = some_value
     val b = value2
     val value3 = some_function_calculation_from other_class
     val c = value3
     val d = value4
    collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(event(a,b),event(c,d)))
  } else {
    collection = sc.parallelize(Seq(event(e,f),event(g,h)))
  }
  collection.saveToCassandra("db", "table", SomeColumns("id", "date"))
  }
}
```

I want to have my collection object to be saved in cassandra with values seq of event(a,b) & event(c,d) and when if condition fails it should be  event(e,f) &  event(g,h) but it is going as null. Where I'm going wrong ?

Note: It works fine when there is no if block that means all collection definition initialisation in one scope.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want collection object to as `RDD[event]` dynamically?

Comment: may be RDD[Array[event]]

Comment: What's wrong with `val xs = if(some_condition) Seq(event(a,b) ) else Seq(event(e,f))` and then parallelizing it later ?

Comment: Hi @philantrovert, Can you please recheck my question, I have edited. I have some more statements inside if block so I think your answer will not work for that situation

Comment: It will, the last statement in the if block will get returned and stored in the variable. All your assignments are of return type Unit anyway. You can also declare explicitly `val xs: Seq[event] = if (...)` to make sure there are no loose ends.

Comment: @philantrovert, Thank you . Yes it worked. Much thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Cool. Just curious, does your old code posted in the question work if you replace declaration of `collection` with `var collection: RDD[event] = ???` ?

Comment: @philantrovert - I guess it was giving some issue. So, I changed it to val instead of var as suggested by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `collection` as `RDD[event]` as per the condition then you could assign `if else` to a variable `collection`.

```
val collection = if (some_condition)
    sc.parallelize(Seq(event("a", "b"), event("c", "d")))
  else
    sc.parallelize(Seq(event("e", "f"), event("g", "h")))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Shankar, Sorry I forgot to mention that I do have some more statements inside If block (edited my question) before parallelize statement so I dont think in that case this answer will work. Can you please recheck ?

Comment: @AdityaJain If you have some statements that will work too, you always have to return `RDD[event]` from and `if` and `else` condition

Comment: Yes , It worked Thank you so much @Shankar. Thank you for your precious time. Accepting your answer.. cheers :)

Comment: @AdityaJain I am glad that helped you. thanks for accepting as answer:)